# Rewwrite rule for mapping plugin static file

Tags: url-rewriting

I am thinking to move my static data to Amazon cloudefront and i am able to map all static data with the URL from the cloudefront except Plugins i have installed.

I do not want to use any plugin to do this mapping as was thinking of writing some kind of rewrite rule to handle this.

for e.g 
all the URL related to plugin static data (js/css etc) have this URL:

```
http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/rest_of_the_url
```

I want to replace this URL with

```
 http://cdn.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/rest_of_the_url
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but the following should do what you want (which is not really WP-specific, BTW):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-content/plugins/
RewriteRule (.*) http://cdn.mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks, but 301 means indicating that it has been moved permanently? additionally i only want to rewrite for js,css and images and rest of the things should be picked from wordpress